# JQ : Change some values and display all the datas?

Tags: json, linux, parsing, jq, cat

I've this data :

```
{
   "cidr" : "X.X.X.X/27",
   "defaultGateway" : "X.X.X.X",
   "full" : false,
   "id" : "X.X.X.X",
   "ipAddressTab" : [
      {
         "alias_domain" : null,
         "alias_name" : null,
         "description" : "This is the network address for X.X.X.X/27",
         "dnr_rr" : null,
         "dns_domain" : null,
         "environnement" : null,
         "fdqn" : null,
         "hostname" : null,
         "ip" : "X.X.X.X",
         "requester" : null,
         "status" : "reserved",
         "type" : "network"
      },
      {
         "alias_domain" : null,
         "alias_name" : null,
         "description" : "This is the default gateway address for X.X.X.X/27",
         "dnr_rr" : null,
         "dns_domain" : null,
         "environnement" : null,
         "fdqn" : null,
         "hostname" : null,
         "ip" : "X.X.X.X",
         "requester" : null,
         "status" : "reserved",
         "type" : "gateway"
      },
      {
         "alias_domain" : "toto.com",
         "alias_name" : "",
         "description" : "this is a test",
         "dns_domain" : "",
         "environnement" : "test",
         "fdqn" : "XXX",
         "hostname" : "XXX",
         "ip" : "X.X.X.X",
         "requester" : "XXX",
         "status" : "allocated",
         "type" : "VM"
      },
      {
         "alias_domain" : "toto.com",
         "alias_name" : "",
         "description" : "this is a test",
         "dns_domain" : "",
         "environnement" : "test",
         "fdqn" : "XXX",
         "hostname" : "XXX",
         "ip" : "X.X.X.X",
         "requester" : "XXX",
         "status" : "allocated",
         "type" : "VM"
      },
      {
         "ip" : "X.X.X.X",
         "status" : "reserved"
      },
      {
         "ip" : "X.X.X.X",
         "status" : "reserved"
      },
      {
         "ip" : "X.X.X.X",
         "status" : "reserved"
      },
      {
         "ip" : "X.X.X.X",
         "status" : "reserved"
      },
      {
         "alias_domain" : null,
         "alias_name" : null,
         "description" : "This is the broadcast address for X.X.X.X/27",
         "dnr_rr" : null,
         "dns_domain" : null,
         "environnement" : null,
         "fdqn" : null,
         "hostname" : null,
         "ip" : "X.X.X.X",
         "requester" : null,
         "status" : "reserved",
         "type" : "broadcast"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to change all status "reserved" as "available" without changing the status for the ip which have network, gateway or broadcast as status. So with jq I'm able to select all I need without select the IPs with network, gateway or broadcast as status and change the status to available :

```
cat myfile |  jq '.ipAddressTab[] | select(.status == "reserved") | select(.type != "network") | select(.type != "gateway") | select(.type != "broadcast") | .status = "available"'
```

The output :

```
{
  "ip": "X.X.X.X",
  "status": "available"
}
{
  "ip": "X.X.X.X",
  "status": "available"
}
{
  "ip": "X.X.X.X",
  "status": "available"
}
{
  "ip": "X.X.X.X",
  "status": "available"
}
```

But there is a way to do that in order to have this output :

```
{
   "cidr" : "X.X.X.X/27",
   "defaultGateway" : "X.X.X.X",
   "full" : false,
   "id" : "X.X.X.X",
   "ipAddressTab" : [
      {
         "alias_domain" : null,
         "alias_name" : null,
         "description" : "This is the network address for X.X.X.X/27",
         "dnr_rr" : null,
         "dns_domain" : null,
         "environnement" : null,
         "fdqn" : null,
         "hostname" : null,
         "ip" : "X.X.X.X",
         "requester" : null,
         "status" : "reserved",
         "type" : "network"
      },
      {
         "alias_domain" : null,
         "alias_name" : null,
         "description" : "This is the default gateway address for X.X.X.X/27",
         "dnr_rr" : null,
         "dns_domain" : null,
         "environnement" : null,
         "fdqn" : null,
         "hostname" : null,
         "ip" : "X.X.X.X",
         "requester" : null,
         "status" : "reserved",
         "type" : "gateway"
      },
      {
         "alias_domain" : "toto.com",
         "alias_name" : "",
         "description" : "this is a test",
         "dns_domain" : "",
         "environnement" : "test",
         "fdqn" : "XXX",
         "hostname" : "XXX",
         "ip" : "X.X.X.X",
         "requester" : "XXX",
         "status" : "allocated",
         "type" : "VM"
      },
      {
         "alias_domain" : "toto.com",
         "alias_name" : "",
         "description" : "this is a test",
         "dns_domain" : "",
         "environnement" : "test",
         "fdqn" : "XXX",
         "hostname" : "XXX",
         "ip" : "X.X.X.X",
         "requester" : "XXX",
         "status" : "allocated",
         "type" : "VM"
      },
      {
         "ip" : "X.X.X.X",
         "status" : "available"
      },
      {
         "ip" : "X.X.X.X",
         "status" : "available"
      },
      {
         "ip" : "X.X.X.X",
         "status" : "available"
      },
      {
         "ip" : "X.X.X.X",
         "status" : "available"
      },
      {
         "alias_domain" : null,
         "alias_name" : null,
         "description" : "This is the broadcast address for X.X.X.X/27",
         "dnr_rr" : null,
         "dns_domain" : null,
         "environnement" : null,
         "fdqn" : null,
         "hostname" : null,
         "ip" : "X.X.X.X",
         "requester" : null,
         "status" : "reserved",
         "type" : "broadcast"
      }
   ]
}
```

Display all the data with the changes desired not just display the lines which should be changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this type of problem, |= is your friend.

You can choose between a straightforward approach, such as:

```
.ipAddressTab
 |= map(if .status == "reserved" 
           and .type != "network"
           and .type != "gateway"
           and .type != "broadcast"
        then .status = "available" else . end)
```

or the more subtle:

```
(.ipAddressTab[]
 | select(.status == "reserved" and 
          .type != "network" and
          .type != "gateway" and
          .type != "broadcast")
).status = "available"
```

Incidentally, a DRYer version of either approach can be obtained by using `IN`:

```
.type | IN("network", "gateway", "broadcast") | not
```

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot !
I had found more or less the same things `.ipAddressTab[] | if .type != "network" and .type != "gateway" and .type != "broadcast" then .status = "available"  else . end`

Thanks !